# Filter elements jQuery start by exp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filtering

Is there any way to show elements which start with an expression in input (research elements by beginning) or something like that.

Here is the code I used to filter, but it didn't work.

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#reportvalid tr").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().match("/\b" + value + "\b/"))
  });
});
```

i want to show only elements start by value in input
please help.

I add some screen of my result
before tapping any things
[image: before taping]

after taping a letter, here i need to show only elements which start by letter 'a'
[image: after taping]

Comment: It seems like you're missing the `hide()`/`show()` calls. Seeing your HTML would also help to reproduce the problem

Comment: toggle() method replace show()/hide().

Comment: everything i tap it show nothings(empty), I will edit post and show you my result

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith check method `startsWith`

Comment: sorry, can't speak russia

Comment: #demo it also not working ( not suported by Internet Explorer) , and  i must use it reasons of my users